# Using CountIf Function to highlight cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 2 lists, i want to find if the values from list 1 included in list 2.

**List 1**
laci      | TRUE
Ask? Gm?d | FALSE
d* *luis  | TRUE
luis* d*  | FALSE

**List 2**
Apolonia Fier |
Atletico Clube De Portugal |
Bregalnica Stip |
Costuleni |
don, luis |

I managed to do that with this formula and wildcards

`=COUNTIF(A5:A104,"*"&F6&"*")>0`

My question now is, how can i highlight the "matched" cell in list 2 ?

It looks so easy but i think its not.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list are on col A & B

Select A1:A10 or B1:B10, which ever list you like to highlight

Go to

**`Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format`**

insert this formula

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)<=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)
```

Click on Format button
Fill --> what ever color you like

[image]

Comment: that is a nice solution but it doesnt support wildcards :/